# Double Regex gives back the wrong number

Tags: c#, regex, double

I made a `Regex` which filters for `double` values.

For example one `TextBox` contains *volume* and I use this `regex` for

```
double ConvertToDouble(String input)
{
    // Matches the first numebr with or without leading minus.
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, "[+-]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");

    if (match.Success)
    { 
        return Double.Parse(match.Value);
    }
    return 0; // Or any other default value.
}
```

Somehow this returns `0` when I enter `0,5` into the `TextBox`.

Comment: `0,5` contains *comma*  `,` when you match for *dot* - `\\.`; that's why you have no match for `[+-]?\\d*\\.?` but for the *last* `\\d+`. I suggest adding *anchors* `^`, `$` - `"^\\s*[+-]?\\d*\\.?\\d+\\s*$"`

Comment: According to [RegExr](https://regexr.com/4m0cl), there will be two matches - `0` and `5`. If, as @DmitryBychenko suggests, you change the comma to a dot, there will be a single match of `0,5`

Comment: You could also consider typing `@"string with \"` to avoid escaping the `\` character

Comment: Why not `double.TryParse`?

Comment: Stupid me. Thank you.

Comment: `1,023,024.37 m^3` might pose problems - if you get numbers like that. Same for `1.203,74 m^3`

Comment: Does not double.tryparse Crash the program if there is no Input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using `double.TryParse` and *get rid* of regex at all:

```
// static : we don't use "this" in the method
static double ConvertToDouble(String input)
{
    // if we can parse input...
    if (double.TryParse(input, out double result))
        return result; // ...return the result of the parsing
    else
        return 0.0;    // otherwise 0.0 or any default value
}
```

Comment: but if for example my TextBox is empty and i try to double.tryparse does it not Crash?? Double.parse crashes for sure is there a difference ?

Comment: @Explorer2501 The Try in TryParse means that it won't throw an exception on empty or invalid input. That's the difference between Parse and TryParse.

Comment: @Explorer2501: If `input` is empty, then `double.TryParse` fail to parse it and return `false` and we on turn return `0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is currently only matching against decimals specified with dot (`.`) and not a comma (`,`).

You could modify the regex to accept either using:

```
[+-]?\d*[\,\.]?\d+
```

In your code:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"[+-]?\d*[\.\,]?\d+");
```

This would match both `0,5` and `0.5`.